# How to add fade effect on this javascript

Tags: javascript, fade, effect

i want just to know how to add fade effect on this javascript code toggle.

```
//<![CDATA[
function toggleList(id, displayValue) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    if(!displayValue)
    {
        var displayValue = (obj.style.display!='none')?'none':'block';

    }
    obj.style.display = displayValue;
    setCookie(id, displayValue, 30);
    return;
}

window.onload = function()
{
    toggleList('sidebar_block_content', getCookie('sidebar_block_content'));
    return;
}

function setCookie(name, value, expiredays)
{
    if (expiredays==null) { expiredays=0; }

    var expireDate = new Date();
    expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate()+expiredays);

    var cookieVal  = name + '=' +escape(value) + ';expires=' + expireDate.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cookieVal; 
    return;
}

function getCookie(searchName)
{
  if (document.cookie.length>0)
  {
    var nameValuePair, cookieName, cookieValue
    var pairs = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++)
    {
      nameValuePair = pairs[i].split('='); 
      cookieName    = nameValuePair[0].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
      cookieValue   = nameValuePair[1].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
      if(cookieName == searchName) { return cookieValue; }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
//]]>
```

This code works on cookies and i want to add a fade effect (like jquery effect) to work with toggle. Can anybody help me with this? :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is a snippet of fading an element at [vanilla-js](http://vanilla-js.com/)

Reproduced below:

```
var s = document.getElementById('thing').style;
s.opacity = 1;
(function fade(){(s.opacity-=.1)<0?s.display="none":setTimeout(fade,40)})();
```

Compared to the jQuery version:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#thing').fadeOut();
</script>
```

Adding a fiddle:

```js
function fadeElement(elem) {
  var s = elem.style;
  s.opacity = 1;
  (function fade(){
    (s.opacity-=.1)<0?s.display="none":setTimeout(fade,40)
  })();
}

fadeElement(document.getElementById('thing'))
```

```html
<div id="thing" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background: red"></div>
```

Comment: Im sorry but your first code dont work.. i need only to modify my code with fade effect ...

Comment: Yes this is okay, but i want this complete with my code (i want to keep my code i mean).. because when i click on my trigger button, i want to toggle my element...

Comment: After or before the `setCookie(id, displayValue, 30);` you can call `fadeElement(obj)`, which will hide the element, you will just need to copy the `fadeElement` function of the above fiddle together with your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
function toggleList(id, displayValue) {
    $( "#" + id).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
       var obj = document.getElementById(id);
           if(!displayValue)
           {
               var displayValue = (obj.style.display!='none')?'none':'block';

           }
           obj.style.display = displayValue;
           setCookie(id, displayValue, 30);
           return;
    });
}
```

Comment: This work fade effect i mean.. but when i click on button to trigger, he hide first and show my element.

Comment: will you share some more code where you are triggering the action. So, I can help you further...

Comment: You can use .fadeToggle() function of JQuery when you trigger the button and you can replace my fadeIn() with this according to your requirement. Please see this, how to use it : http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/

Comment: I cannot do this.. i think im too noob.. if anyone can help me with this i will appreciate.. i give up.

Comment: Will you please share your further more code, if you want a well descriptive help.

Answer (score 0):

So. 
1. I have first code of this subject. 
2. I have this line:

```
<a href="#" class="toggle_sidebarBody toggle_sdautoHide clickable" title="{L_SD_TOGGLE_SIDEBAR}" onclick="toggleList('sidebar_block_content'); return false;">{L_SD_COLLAPSE_ENTITY}</a>
```

for toggle, and my content X.

When i click on toggle button i want my content to hide / show with fade effect.